# Teradata - Remove whitespace within a varchar

Tags: teradata

I have a table with varchar columns that have whitespace between the text (e.g: S O C I A L). I've tried using the following to remove the whitespace:

- regexp_replace([column], '[[:space:]]{2,}', '')
- regexp_replace([column], '[\s]', '', 1, 0, 'c')
- regexp_replace([column], ' ', '')
- oreplace([column], '[\s]', '')
- oreplace([column], ' ', '')

But so far nothing has worked, so I'm not really sure what to do since Teradata SQL doesn't have the usual replace function.

Comment: What kind of *whitespace*? Blanks, tabs, linebreaks, etc.? Blanks only: `OReplace(col, ' ', '')` or `OTranslate(col, ' ', '')`
, otherwise `RegExp_Replace(col, '[\s]', '', 1, 0, 'c')`.

Comment: I realized what was causing that problem, I loaded the table through FastLoad using a unicode file instead of ASCII. whoops

Comment: Ok, now that whitespace is hex `00`xc :-) Better reload the data, because Teradata silently truncates (e.g. inserting `SOCIAL` into a VarChar(5) will result in `SOCIA'), and your strings doubled in size during load.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I used standard ASCII and it worked properly now